# Deezer js SDK getLoginStatus response status values

Tags: deezer

I've been playing around with the getLoginStatus method of Deezer js SDK. On the documentation page, it is stated that the possible values for the response status are;

- connected
- notConnected
- not_authorized
- unknown

The meaning of these statuses are not documented, so I run a few tests. In my test cases;

If the user is logged into Deezer in the browser and is connected to my app, the returned status is "connected"

If the user is logged into Deezer in the browser but is not connected to my app, the returned status is "not_authorized"

If the user is not logged into Deezer in the browser, the returned status is "unknown"

So, in which case "notConnected" is returned as the status value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'notconnected' status is the default status, and is only used on logout actually.